# Firefox Print HTML page cuts off content

Tags: html, css, firefox, printing

I have a html page, I want to print with the browser. In IE9 and Chrome, everything works as expected, but on Firefox, the page is cut off. See HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <style>
        .grid {
            list-style: none;
            margin-left: -20px;
        }

        .grid > .col-1-3, .grid > .col-2-6, .grid  > .col-4-12 {
            width: 33.33333%;
        }

        .col {
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            display: inline-block;
            margin-right: -.25em;
            min-height: 1px;
            padding-left: 20px;
            vertical-align: top;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="middle">
        <div class="grid">
            <main class="col col-2-3" id="main">
                <article>
                    <h1>Page Title</h1>

                    <div class="sec">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="grid sec">

                        <div class="col col-2-3">
                            <h2>LEFT TITLE</h2>

                            <table>


                                <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="text-right" >40</td>
                                    <th>g</th>
                                    <th>
                                        <a href="#">Foo</a>
                                    </th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="text-right" >40</td>
                                    <th>g</th>
                                    <th>
                                        <a href="#">Ba</a>
                                    </th>
                                </tr>


                                <tr>
                                    <td class="text-right" data-amount="4">4</td>
                                    <th>kg</th>
                                    <th>
                                        <a href="#">Trallala</a>
                                    </th>
                                </tr>


                                <tr>
                                    <td class="text-right" data-amount="200">200</td>
                                    <th>g</th>
                                    <th>
                                        <a href="#">Bla</a>
                                    </th>
                                </tr>


                                <tr>
                                    <td class="text-right" data-amount="300">300</td>
                                    <th>ml</th>
                                    <th>
                                        <a href="#">Blub</a>
                                    </th>
                                </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col col-1-3 recipe-rightbar">
                            <div>
                                <h2>RIGHT SIDEBAR Title</h2>
                                <ul>
                                    <li>List item 1</li>
                                    <li>List item 2</li>
                                    <li>List item 3</li>
                                    <li>List item 4</li>
                                    <li>List item 5</li>
                                    <li>List item 6</li>
                                    <li>List item 7</li>
                                </ul>

                                <div>
                                    <h2> RIGHT SIDEBAR Title</h2>
                                    <ol>
                                        <li>List item 1</li>
                                        <li>List item 2</li>
                                        <li>List item 3</li>
                                        <li>List item 4</li>
                                        <li>List item 5</li>
                                        <li>List item 6</li>
                                        <li>List item 7</li>
                                    </ol>
                                </div>

                                <div>
                                    <h2> RIGHT SIDEBAR Title</h2>
                                    <ol>
                                        <li>List item 1</li>
                                        <li>List item 2</li>
                                        <li>List item 3</li>
                                        <li>List item 4</li>
                                        <li>List item 5</li>
                                        <li>List item 6</li>
                                        <li>List item 7</li>
                                    </ol>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <section class="sec ">
                        <h2>Title</h2>
                        <ol>
                            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eosrebum.</li>

                            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscingeirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. adsadasd</li>

                            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.</li>

                            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,  nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.</li>

                            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitd tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.</li>

                            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit aur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.</li>
                        </ol>
                    </section>

                    <section>
                        <h2>Title</h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.</p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.</p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.</p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.</p>
                    </section>
                </article>
            </main>
        </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Has anybody an idea how to solve this issue?

I have already tried to set overflow visible to every element:

```
    * {
        overflow: visible;
    }
```

but that didn't solve the problem.

I have tested the code in Firefox33, IE9 and Chrome38, but only Firefox failed to print the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the `display: inline-block;` bit, there are many ways to resolve the issues with css, I'm not sure what the end result is supposed to look like though.

Comment: But how to solve it? The end result in Firefox should look like in Chrome or IE. This means, it should print more than 1 page and don't cut the text off. I have updated the question with an example how it looks like in FF and how it should look like (printed with chrome)

Comment: well you could remove the  `display: inline-block;` bit for one thing.

Comment: I know, that I the inline-block is the problem, but if I remove it, the result doesn't look like as expected. I will try to solve it with display: table-cell.