# HTML Iframe content displays completely in browser, but on print some content is cut off

Tags: html, css, angular, iframe

This issue has been discussed on SO several times. Below are the posts I referred but none of them helped.

[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26778158/firefox-print-html-page-cuts-off-content)

[Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22965175/iframe-content-gets-cut-off-when-printing)

[Link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15608012/iframe-inside-div-cut-off-content)

[Link4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12318650/iframe-100-height-issue)

The contents of Iframe displays fine in browser (Chrome/ FireFox) but when I use the browser's print functionality, the contents are not completely printed. The print preview shows that the last line is cut off.
Using height: 100vh is not acceptable because lot of blank spaces are left behind after the content.

Please see the stackblitz to recreate the issue....
[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hvrtdy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)
I am manually setting the height to 204px in reality I intend to dynamically get the content's height and set the value

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by setting the height in pt rather than setting it in px values. Please feel free to add why pt works and not px.